# can't git-push to heroku due to "Build stream timed out"

Tags: django, git, heroku

I have a Django app on heroku, I commited and pushed many time before but on the last time I've tried to push I got this error (and I keep getting it):

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 24.22 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: Build stream timed out, reverting to polling..........................
..............................................................................
```

Seems like it is not going to stop.
why does it happens and what can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I'm seeing this now.  When I check https://status.heroku.com/ I see that there is an issue and they write "We have temporarily disabled application builds to reduce error rate while we continue investigating this issue."

So the issue is probably not related to your app.

Comment: Note that it is possible that you may look at https://status.heroku.com/ before they even have a chance to post the notice... check back in a few minutes and you may see something: "Increased Build Failure Rate - We're currently investigating an increase in build failures."

Comment: Just had the same issue a couple years later, found your answer, and, sure enough, the Heroku status page shows an issue right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Wait an hour and then try again, I'm not kidding!

Answer (score 4):

Mine did that for a while then eventually just went through without me doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and going to the "Activity" tab for the app on my Heroku dashboard, I can see details of the build. For me, the details indicated the slug size was too large. Try going to your Heroku dashboard and get more info about the reason for the build failing.

Comment: there was nothing relevant to this problem in this tab for me

Comment: Thanks, in my case the activity tab showed the build was going on normally, it's just the terminal that got disconnected I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to push the changes gradually. I picked an older commit and pushed that first, before pushing HEAD. Apparently, there were just too many commits to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the reason for this problem, and I don't know how to fix it.
However, I bypass it by cloning the project to a new workspace directory and work from there. I guess something just became corrupted in my previous working directory

Comment: This is just an specific workaround. The solution is to wait for Heroku to fix the build process.

Comment: There was no problem with your previous working directory. What fixed it was time - within which the issue at Heroku was resolved. You should delete this question and accept the one by @user1515295 re: https://status.heroku.com/